# flutter for web render Html with TextAlign.justify and rtl

Tags: flutter-web

I want to show a html code in one of my flutter web page and I used 'flutter_html'. this is part of my code:

```
Html(
     data: """<p dir="rtl">آمادگی و شناخت</p><p dir="rtl">در مشاوره ازدواج به دو فرآیند توجه می شود؛ اول این که فرد بداند برای ازدواج آمادگی دارد یا نه و بعد از طرف مقابل شناخت کافی داشته باشد. فرد برای این که بداند آمادگی ازدواج دارد یا نه، می تواند از مشاور کمک بگیرد. فردی آمادگی ازدواج دارد که تعهد پایدار داشته باشد، یعنی برای فردی که وارد زندگی او شده است بار نباشد، زندگی بالنده ای داشته باشد، باعث آرامش وی شود، سرعت حرکت او را به سمت تعالی و پیشرفت بیشتر کند و اگر چنین نباشد، در واقع ازدواج تنها برای رفع بخشی از نیازها خواهد بود که به فرد برای پیشرفت و تعالی کمک نمی کند. بنابراین برای این که فرد میزان آمادگی خود را برآورد کند می تواند از مشاور حاذق در این حوزه کمک بگیرد. مشاور باید درباره موضوعات مختلف اطلاعات کافی داشته باشد و مولفه ها را بر اساس اهمیت آن بررسی کند. در مشاوره قبل از ازدواج دو عامل آمادگی و آشنایی مهم است.</p>
            """,
     defaultTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
     useRichText: true,
     customTextAlign: (_) => TextAlign.justify,
                ),
```

I want my text be justify and rtl  but it's not rtl and just TextAlign.justify work, look like " p dir="rtl" " do not render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer, first must keep these parts of old code

```
useRichText: true,
customTextAlign: (_) => TextAlign.justify
```

then add html as child of:

```
Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: Html...)
```